# Plotting Multiple Plots using boxplot in R

Tags: r, statistics

I'm currently using R to create boxplots to compare the outcomes of measuring two sets of two different variables, e.g., measuring speed in honda vs toyota
then measuring speed in red vs blue (I've just made this up off the top of my head for the purpose of the question).

The current code I'm using is

```
boxplot(my.data$speed ~ my.data$`honda/toyota`, main = "A", ylab = "speed in km")
```

then

```
boxplot(my.data$speed ~ my.data$`red/blue`, main = "A", ylab = "speed in km")
```

Is there any way I can combine the two plots to have them on one graph?

Answer (score 0):

In base R, you need to call something like:

```
par(mfrow = c(1,2)) # Do an panel plot with 1 row, and 2 columns
plot(1)  # Your plot 1
plot(2)  # Your plot 2
```

See `?par` for more information. Alternatively, you can use the `mfcol` argument in `par` or use the `layout` function. The latter might be considered a bit more flexible. Both both approaches are useful when you want to do simple plots with multiple panels.

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply!! I see what you mean, but what I wanted was the four data sets i.e, "red, blue, honda, toyota" all on one boxplot, rather than two separate graphs side by side which is what the par comes up with...